# Paragraphs extend outside of div with designated width and height

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs with `float:left`. Both have designated widths, heights, paddings and margins. But on one of the divs the content with its paragraphs tags dramatically overflows the right edge of the div.

My CSS is set out us such:

Content in this div behaves as expected:

```
#upcomingevents
{
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Content in this div overflows the right side, creating a scroll bar:

```
#maincontent
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    height: 400px;
    width: 555px;
    margin: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Both these divs are wrapped in a div that has `overflow:auto`

```
#contentinner
{
    overflow: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto auto 60px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

I am really puzzled as to why the `#maincontent` `p`'s are behaving this way. Can anyone tell me what I'm done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's one continuous line. Add

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

to `#textcontent > p` tags to break the lines